# CRS USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal not working

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have selected the USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic, yet the map is showing a different projection.  It worked when I started the project and something went wrong after I did a "print composer".  Now it doesn't work even if I start a new project and re-do all the steps.  Any idea how I can fix this? 
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to override the coordinate system at the layer level, which you shouldn't do - the layer coordinate system should be left alone (guessing it came in WGS84/4326?) - in the bottom right, the EPSG:102003 should have (OTF) after it, which means the source coordinate system of the layer is being projected ON THE FLY (OTF), which is what you should be after...

Answer (score 1):

You probably have used `Set Layer CRS` to switch from a degree CRS to Albers equal. This is the wrong tool, and it has corrupted your data. So you better set it back to WGS84 or NAD83.

Instead, use `Raster -> Projections -> Warp` to a different filename and target CRS, and remove the original layer from your canvas.

Comment: Thank you.  I followed instructions from a video on Youtube to create choropleth maps which clearly said that I should use Set Layer CRS to change projections.  How do I change the CRS, if I shouldn't be using the Set Layer CRS?  What I am trying to do is join a data file (csv) with US State boundaries shape file and create a choropleth map.

Comment: For CSV and vector data, use `Save as ...` to a different filename and target CRS. Can you add a link to that video?